# RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am working with firebase database .I was update the dependence  .Then it in not working and showing me this Error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I updated my sdk version

```
compileSdkVersion 27

//buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
//buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hasib.foodapplication"

    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled = true
```

This is my firebase tools dependence.Which i found from firebase document site.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

This is play service dependence

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

This is my project gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

This is Android database ui

```
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
```

I don't know how to solve this error. I googled this for hours but with no success.

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Please read through all the solutions on the linked question, of which this one is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please change all dependencies either to compile or implementation depending on your android studio version. Next there is a dependency for multidex please do add it and let me know if that works ?

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Comment: Which dependencies  i should change?

Comment: You should either change all dependencies to compile or to implementation.

Comment: If i change the version i got another error .They say that to update the version.I am confused ..I am using android 3.0.1

Comment: What android studio version are you using ?

Comment: I am using android 3.0.1

Comment: Then change all 'compile' keywords to implementation

Comment: ok..I i will info you.

Comment: i converted compile to implementation ..But remain same ..

Comment: Add this dependency, then clean and rebuild the project:   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Comment: Did that work for you @HasibAkon ??